# jQuery JSON parsererror even though JSON is valid

Tags: json, jquery, jsonp

I am trying to pull in some external JSON phone list for a test I am doing locally.

JSON = https://www.o2.co.uk/shop/homepage/scripts/phoneList.json

I have read on a seperate thread that to overcome allow origin / cross domain issues you can pass 'callback=?' to the end of the url. This seems to work fine as now in the devtools network tab I can see the file being pulled in fine.

However, I never get it to go into the success callback function. It always brings back a **parsererror**.

The code is 100% valid according to jsonlint.com

A snippet of the code as below:

```
$.ajax({
          type: 'GET',
          url: 'https://www.o2.co.uk/shop/homepage/scripts/phoneList.json?callback=?',
          contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
          cache: true,
          dataType:'json',
          success: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
          },
          error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(jqXHR);
            console.log(textStatus);
            console.log(errorThrown);
          }
        });
```

Any ideas welcome as I am well and truly stuck.

Thanks.

Comment: you are trying to use `jsonp` on a resource which doesnot seems to support it

Comment: just passing `callback=?` does not make a request cross domain the server side need to support such a response

Comment: Not entirely certain but the JSON returned from the Url is an array and not an object - this may upset the parser.

Comment: but i can see the file and response in devtools? so the file isnt being blocked or anything?

Comment: The service doesn't seem to support CORS, hence you are not allowed to access it via Ajax.

Answer (score 0):

JSONP only works if the server supports it. What the server needs to do, is take your callback parameter and wrap the json data in a function call with that name.

So when `https://www.o2.co.uk/shop/homepage/scripts/phoneList.json` responds with

```
[{
"handset":"Alcatel 10.30 Black",
"link":"/shop/phones/alcatel/10.30-black/"
}]
```

`https://www.o2.co.uk/shop/homepage/scripts/phoneList.json?callback=MyCallback` should respond with:

```
MyCallback([{
"handset":"Alcatel 10.30 Black",
"link":"/shop/phones/alcatel/10.30-black/"
}]);
```

If the server doesn't do that, JSONP can't work. Perhaps O2 doesn't want you using their data.